# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't attach instance another instance with key is already present in this session

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Here I have a problem for which I can't find the solution.  I've tried to detach category objects with `expunge` but once it's added it doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/scwall/PycharmProjects/purebeurre/recovery.py", line 171, in <module>
        connection.connect.add(article)
      File "/home/scwall/PycharmProjects/purebeurre/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1776, in add
        self._save_or_update_state(state)
      File "/home/scwall/PycharmProjects/purebeurre/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1796, in _save_or_update_state
        self._save_or_update_impl(st_)
      File "/home/scwall/PycharmProjects/purebeurre/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2101, in _save_or_update_impl
        self._update_impl(state)
      File "/home/scwall/PycharmProjects/purebeurre/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2090, in _update_impl
        self.identity_map.add(state)
      File "/home/scwall/PycharmProjects/purebeurre/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/identity.py", line 149, in add
        orm_util.state_str(state), state.key))
    sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't attach instance <Categories at 0x7fe8d8000e48>; another instance with key (<class 'packages.databases.models.Categories'>, (26,), None) is already present in this session.
```

```py
class CategoriesQuery(ConnectionQuery):
    
    @classmethod
    def get_categories_by_tags(cls, tags_list):
        return cls.connection.connect.query(
            Categories
        ).filter(Categories.id_category.in_(tags_list)).all()
```

other file:

```py
 def function_recovery_and_push(link_page):

        list_article = []
        try:
            products_dic = requests.get(link_page).json()
            for product in products_dic["products"]:
                if 'nutrition_grades' in product.keys() \
                        and 'product_name_fr' in product.keys() \
                        and 'categories_tags' in product.keys() \
                        and 1 <= len(product['product_name_fr']) <= 100:
                    try:
                        list_article.append(
                            Products(name=product['product_name_fr'], description=product['ingredients_text_fr'],
                                     nutrition_grade=product['nutrition_grades'], shop=product['stores'],
                                     link_http=product['url'],
                                     categories=CategoriesQuery.get_categories_by_tags(product['categories_tags'])))

                    except KeyError:
                        continue

            list_article.append(count_and_end_page_return_all)
            return list_article

        except:
            list_article.append(count_and_end_page_return_all)
            return list_article


    p = Pool()
    articles_list_all_pool = p.map(function_recovery_and_push, list_page_for_pool)
    p.close()

    for articles_list_pool in articles_list_all_pool:
        for article in articles_list_pool:
                connection.connect.add(article)
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, not sure you implemented the models as same as I did, but in my case at least, I had in the table's model - i.e:

```
product_items = relationship(...)
```

So later when I tried to do

```
products = session.query(Products).all()

one_of_the_products = products[0]
new_product = ProductItem(product_id=one_of_the_products.id, name='foo', category='bla')
session.add(new_product)
```

It raises the same exception as you:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't attach instance <ProductItem at 0x7fe8d8000e48>; another instance with key (<class 'packages.databases.models.ProductItem'>, (26,), None) is already present in this session.
```

The reason for the exception, is that when I queried for `products` - the `relationship` created it's own sub-query and attached the `product_item`'s objects, it placed them in the variable name I defined in the `relationship()` -> `product_items`.

So instead of doing:

```
session.add(new_product)
```

I just had to use the relationship:

```
one_of_the_products.product_items.append(new_product)
session.commit()
```

hope it helps others.

Answer (score 2):

This error message is emitted when an ORM model instance is added to a session when another instance of the model with *the same primary key* already exists in the session.

This is an example that would raise, based on the [SQLAlchemy session unit tests](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/f7b40c0102c33faf350917f5b98c61d4c6fbec90/test/orm/test_session.py#L1122):

```py
with Session() as s:
    instance1 = MyModel()
    s.add(instance1)
    s.flush()
    s.expunge(instance1)
    instance2 = s.get(MyModel, instance1.id)
    s.add(instance1)  # <- this line will raise
```

The case in the question is more complicated. The error is raised for a related model (`Category`) rather than the model being added (`Products`) and the categories, which already exist in the database, are retrieved in multiple sessions (because multiprocessing is being used).

Since categories are being retrieved in multiple sessions it's possible that a situation like this may arise:

```py
session.add(Products(categories=[category1_from_session1]))
session.add(Products(categories=[category1_from_session2]))
```

In this case the second `add()` will fail, because `category1_from_session1` already exists in the session, and `category1_from_session2` has the same primary key but is not the same Python instance, that is:

```py
# Both of these statements are true.
category1_from_session1.id == category1_from_session2.id
category1_from_session1 is not category1_from_session2
```

As the category data is the same regardless of the session that retrieved it, the solution is to [merge](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge) the objects into the session rather than [add](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.add)ing them.

Here's a full example based on the case in the question:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(orm.DeclarativeBase):
    pass


assoc = sa.Table(
    't48601123a',
    Base.metadata,
    sa.Column(
        'product_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('t48601123p.id'), primary_key=True
    ),
    sa.Column(
        'category_id', sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('t48601123c.id'), primary_key=True
    ),
)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't48601123p'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    categories: Mapped[list['Category']] = orm.relationship(
        secondary=assoc, back_populates='products'
    )


class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 't48601123c'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    products: Mapped[list[Product]] = orm.relationship(
        secondary=assoc, back_populates='categories'
    )


engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = orm.sessionmaker(engine)

with Session.begin() as s:
    category = Category(name='A')
    s.add(category)

products = []

with Session() as s:
    cats1 = s.scalars(sa.select(Category).where(Category.name.in_(['A']))).all()
    products.append(Product(categories=cats1))

with Session() as s:
    cats2 = s.scalars(sa.select(Category).where(Category.name.in_(['A']))).all()
    products.append(Product(categories=cats2))

with Session.begin() as s:
    for product in products:
        s.merge(product)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you try to add an object to a session but it is already loaded.

The only line that I see you use .add function is at the end where you run:
`connection.connect.add(article)`

So my guess is that this Model is already loaded in the session and you don't need to add it again. You can add a try, except and rollback the operation if it throws an exception.

Answer (score -1):

unloading all objects from session and then adding it again in session might help.

```py
db.session.expunge_all()
db.session.add()
```